How to synchronize scrollbar with highlighted label in a resizable Tkinter window?
I’m working on a Tkinter application that includes a scrollable frame of labels. I’ve implemented functionality to scroll through the labels and highlight a selected label using buttons. However, I’m encountering an issue where, upon resizing the main window, the scrollbar and the highlighted label become out of sync. The scrollbar continues to function, but the highlighted label moves out of the visible area.
Here’s a simplified version of the code that demonstrates the problem:
import tkinter as tk

class ScrollableFrame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.on_frame_configure)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        self.labels = []
        for i in range(10):
            label = tk.Label(self.frame, text=f"Label {i}", bg="white")
            label.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill="x")
            self.labels.append(label)

        self.scroll_down_button = tk.Button(self, text="Scroll Down", command=self.scroll_down)
        self.scroll_down_button.pack(side="left")

        self.scroll_up_button = tk.Button(self, text="Scroll Up", command=self.scroll_up)
        self.scroll_up_button.pack(side="left")

        self.select_button = tk.Button(self, text="Select", command=self.select_label)
        self.select_button.pack(side="left")

        self.current_label_index = 0
        self.highlight_label(self.current_label_index)

    def on_frame_configure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_canvas_configure(self, event):
        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_frame, width=canvas_width)
        self.update_scroll_position()

    def update_scroll_position(self):
        # Get the current view position of the scrollbar
        current_view = self.canvas.yview()
        # Calculate the position of the current label
        label_y = self.labels[self.current_label_index].winfo_y()
        # Calculate the height of the frame
        frame_height = self.frame.winfo_height()
        # Calculate the new position for the scrollbar thumb
        new_position = label_y / frame_height
        # Set the scrollbar to the new position
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(new_position)

    def scroll_down(self):
        if self.current_label_index < len(self.labels) - 1:
            self.unhighlight_label(self.current_label_index)
            self.current_label_index += 1
            self.highlight_label(self.current_label_index)
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units")

    def scroll_up(self):
        if self.current_label_index > 0:
            self.unhighlight_label(self.current_label_index)
            self.current_label_index -= 1
            self.highlight_label(self.current_label_index)
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units")

    def select_label(self):
        label_text = self.labels[self.current_label_index].cget("text")
        print(label_text)

    def highlight_label(self, index):
        self.labels[index].configure(bg="yellow")

    def unhighlight_label(self, index):
        self.labels[index].configure(bg="white")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ScrollableFrame()
    app.mainloop()

The expected behavior is that the highlighted label should always remain in view and in sync with the scrollbar position, even after the window is resized.
What I’ve tried so far:

Binding a method to the  event of the canvas to update the scroll region.
Adjusting the canvas view in the scroll_up and scroll_down methods.

Despite these attempts, the issue persists. How can I ensure that the highlighted label remains visible and in sync with the scrollbar after the window is resized?
You can look at the pictures below:
https://i.sstatic.net/M6GwQ3ep.png
This part shows the problem:
https://i.sstatic.net/HlnwyD7O.png

why can't you call function update_scroll_position in both functions scroll_down and scroll_up at the end, instead of calling self.canvas.yview_scroll(…)?
